# how to protect static int in C#

Tags: c#

I am learning C# so I am still on the basics here. This is my code

```
class foo
{
  protected int id;
  protected string data;
  static int nextId = 1;

  public int Id
  {
    get { return id; }
  }

  public foo()
  {
    this.id = nextId++;
  }
  public foo(string somedata)
  {
    this.data = somedata;
    this.id = nextId++;
  }
}
```

This code works just fine for now. All objects will have a unique ID with them.

Problem is: I don't want the first ID to be 1, I want it to be the number on the first line of the file given as an argument to the application from the commandline. If no file is specified or the file does not exist, then it can be one. **Is there a way to make a one-time method to set nextId so it cannot be tampered with outside of the class after it has been once set?**

Duh... I guess this is the trick. Still, I'd like to know if there is some build in way to make variables that can only be set once.

```
public int nextId
{
  set {if(nextId<1) nextId = value;}
}
```

Comment: You can create a public static method SetIndex which will assign value nextId. And make nextId private.

Comment: Make `NextId` a property and use a boolean to indicate if the value has been set. If set again, throws exception?

Comment: How about extracting this from `foo`? Inject an `IdService`.

Comment: If I make nextId private, it starts as 1 with all objects doens't it? I want all objects created from this class to have a unique id. Also, I don't know it the solution I came up with is actually as good as it first seemed...

Comment: Maybe take a look at [access modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers).

Comment: Thanks Fildor. So if I make a class that inherits from this class, they can't use private variables & methods but protected members are inherited or am I not understanding correctly?

Comment: Woops! Now I realize my error with access modifiers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement *static constructor*, which assigns proper value to `nextId` before first usage of `foo` class:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq; 
...

class foo
{
  ...
  static int nextId;

  // read-only property which however can be assigned in the constructor
  public int Id {get;}

  // This static costructor will be called once before 1st usage of foo class
  static foo() {
    //TODO: put the right file name here
    string fileName = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1];

    nextId = int.Parse(File 
      .ReadLines(fileName)
      .First());  
  }

  public foo()
  {
    //Let's increment nextId in thread-safe manner
    Id = Interlocked.Increment(ref nextId);
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
class foo
{
  private static int nextId = 1;
  private static bool isNextIdSet;

  public SetId(newId)
  {
    if (!isNextIdSet) nextId = newId;
    isNextIdSet = true;
  }
}
```

So the nextId can be set only once from outside the class.

UPDATE: if you prefer to use this with many variables, you can create a helper for this, such as

```
class SetOnlyOnce<T>
{
  private bool isSet;
  public T Value
  { 
    get;
    set
    {
      if (!isSet) Value = value;
      isSet = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Then use it as

```
class Foo
{
  public SetOnlyOnce<int> prop1 {get;set;}
  public SetOnlyOnce<string> prop2 {get;set;}
}

class Bar
{
  public Bar()
  {
    var foo = new Foo();
    foo.prop1.Value = 2;
    foo.prop1.Value = 3; // this doesn't set.
  }
}
```

Comment: how about `int?`

Comment: I just change to use a bool, it makes more sense. Since other classes still can reset the value back to default, and set to new value again.

Comment: I guess that's another question.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to [Dmitry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60755589/4247453), you can define the initialization through a static method. I prefer avoiding static constructors unless multiple fields need to be initialized simultaneously.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq; 
...

class foo
{
  ...
  // The initialization will be called at some time before first use of nextId.
  private static int nextId = GenerateInitialNextId();

  // read-only property which however can be assigned in the constructor
  public int Id {get;}

  private static int GenerateInitialNextId() {
    //TODO: put the right file name here
    string fileName = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1];

    return int.Parse(File 
      .ReadLines(fileName)
      .First());  
  }

  public foo()
  {
    //Let's increment nextId is thread-safe manner
    Id = Interlocked.Increment(ref nextId);
  }

  ...
}
```